# How can i make URLEncoding not encode colon?

Tags: java, android

I have a JSONObject:

```
{user:{"firstname":"testuser","surname":"æøå"}}
```

So i have these special characters in the object

I URLEncode the jsonString i have.

```
urlEncodedJsonReq = URLEncoder.encode("{user:{\"firstname\":\"testuser\",\"surname\":\"æøå\"}}","UTF-8");
```

I get a response from the server: "The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.".
This is the encoded url: `serverurl/%7Buser%3A%7B%22firstname%22%3A%22testuser%22%2C%22surname%22%3A%22%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5%22%7D%7D`

But what i need it to be:

```
%7Buser:%7B%22firstname%22:%22testuser%22%2C%22surname%22:%22%C3%A6%C3%B8%C3%A5%22%7D%7D
```

Is this possible in any reasonable way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, or simply:

```
URLEncoder.encode(theUrl).replace("%3A", ":");
```

Comment: Do you make the change in the library?